# Apache Superset - logo changes not working

Tags: docker-compose, apache-superset

I am new in using superset.

I am using apache superset 3.1.1 and I need to change the logo. I created one logo and copied in the folder but it seems its not working.

I cloned the apache superset from github. Using release superset-3.1.1.

To run with docker compose i am using the command "docker-compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml up".

I copied my logo under superset-frontend/src/assets/images as shown in attached
[image: superset logo image]

I have done the changes also in superset_config file
[image: superset config file changes]

under the path as per attached
[image: superst config path]

After running the "docker-compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml up" I can see the login page but without my logo
[image: login page without my logo]

Also, I tried to run the build command but it didn't work.